# Add meta.stackoverflow.com to the reputation leagues

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, reputation-leagues

Can we get meta included in the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/)? I feel so unloved.

And I'm not even asking for it to be called *The league of extraordinary unicorns*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is done.  No freehand circles?

Comment: You totally made my day :)